# HTTP cache headers CDN serving content that never changes

Tags: caching, nginx, cdn

I am serving static images that never change with an ad server and I see that the http headers include the following:

Cache-Control: max-age=315360000

Pragma: public

Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate

How do I make browsers cache the data ?
My origin server is an nginx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `expires max;` to the location for your static images, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires

Update:

to apply this to a specific directory - let's say a subdir images- you would add the following:

```
location /images/ {
  expires max;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me of this output is good :If-Modified-Since: Fri, 09 Nov 2012 23:54:59 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Server: nginx/0.7.65
Date: Thu, 15 Nov 2012 10:49:09 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Nov 2012 23:54:59 GMT
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Pragma: public
X-Cache: MISS from ams-ch-4.cdn.peer1.net
X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from ams-ch-4.cdn.peer1.net:81
Via: 1.0 ams-ch-4.cdn.peer1.net:81 (squid)
----------------------------------------------------------

Comment: hm, something weird is going on: you have 2 cache-control headers, one of which is set to max-age=0 (which basically means don't use the cached version). The 2nd Cache control header and the Expires one look ok. Probably has something to do with the squid proxy  that (from the headers) is in between your client and the server. Try accessing the content without the squid in between to narrow down where the problem originates.